# PHP Url Parameters with Square Brackets

Tags: php, get, urlencode

I want to send the following json to the **PHP** server in a **GET** request

`{"filters":{"abc]def":"xyz"}}`

My request url looks like this

- before encode: `https://test.com?filter[abc]def]=xyz`
- after encode: `https://test.com?filter%5Babc%5Ddef%5D=xyz`

But server `$_GET` becomes `['filter'=>['abc'=>'xyz']]`

Is there a way to make the server `$_GET` equal to `['filter'=>['abc]def'=>'xyz']]` ?

Comment: you could `base64_encode` the payload and then decode before processing